# FireFox "window._laq is undefined" Error.. works in Chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have code that works in Chrome and IE to pop-up a chat window but not working in FireFox.
-  FireFox error "TypeError: window._laq is undefined"

The JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if (!window._laq) { window._laq = []; }
  window._laq.push(function(){chat.showWhenOnline('123123', document.getElementById('chat_button_online_123123'));
  chat.showWhenOffline('123123', document.getElementById('chat_button_offline_123123'));
  });
</script>
```

It's is called by clicking an image button.. The code:

```
<a class="chaticon" id="chat_button_online_123123" 
onclick="chat.startChat('123123')">
<img src="http://myDomain.com/chatIcon_on.jpg" border="0" alt="Need Help? Live Chat!" />
</a>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks
/Shane

Comment: what does `href="javascript://Chat"` do that isn't handled by your `onclick` handler?

Comment: Good question... I removed it, It did not fix the FireFox not working/error.

Comment: Is there a link to a full page showing the problem?  The snippets on their own are not showing the problem for me.

Comment: @ Boris... unfortunately its an internal/intranet site.. so there is no access from the outside.

Answer (score 0):

you have to insert

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://c.la1-c1cs-lon.salesforceliveagent.com/content/g/js/34.0/deployment.js'></script>
```

before your script. 
In that way the system should recognize the command window._laq.

Comment: Hello.  Do you know that your question, [Excel: how to create multiple rows from one](http://superuser.com/q/938355/150988), was migrated to Super User about 1½ months ago?  I wrote an answer to it.  If you're still interested in the question, please [join the Super User community](https://superuser.com/users/join?returnurl=http%3a%2f%superuser.com%2fq%2f938355%2f150988), read [it](http://superuser.com/a/961781/150988), and let me know whether it's useful to you.